# Empty alert changes function behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I have the strangest Bug, my Javascript function behaves differently depending on wether or not an alert is set on a specific Line.

Basically the Code looks like this:

```
var friendsHtml = 'Error String';
$.get("url", function(xml){
    $(xml).find('friend').each(function(){
        friendsHtml = 'html stuff';
    });
});
var div = '<div>'+friendsHtml+'</div>';
$("#friends_window").html(div);
```

Which will always display the Error String and not the HTML String.
But when i add an empty alert on this line, everything works just fine:

```
var friendsHtml = 'Error String';
$.get("url", function(xml){
    $(xml).find('friend').each(function(){
        friendsHtml = 'html stuff';
    });
});
alert("");
var div = '<div>'+friendsHtml+'</div>';
$("#friends_window").html(div);
```

I really don't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `alert` blocks ("pauses") the execution of the function, but not the AJAX request.

So, when you hit "OK" to dismiss the alert dialog, the request may have finished, and the `friendsHtml` variable is then changed by the callback method in `jQuery.get`.

A visualisation:

```
// Case 1
var friendsHtml = 'Error String';
< sending AJAX request... >
var div = '<div>'+friendsHtml+'</div>';  // <AJAX request hasn't finished yet
                                         // so "Error String" is printed.
// Case 2:
...
< sending AJAX request >
alert("");                           // <-- Blocks execution
                                     // Meanwhile, AJAX request finishes
                                     // and changes friendsHtml to "html stuff"
< User dismisses dialog, and the execution is resumed >
var div = '<div>'+friendsHtml+'</div>'; // <-- "html stuff"
```

Comment: Of course! I have to make a synchronous request for this to work.

Comment: @Dreiven Synchronous requests should be avoided where possible, because they block the User's interface until the request has completed. Your code doesn't look *that* important, so an async request with a properly coded callback method should do the job well.

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening is that the div is being updated before the `$.get()` is allowed to finish. You could possibly put the div update code inside of the callback function for `$.get()`. You might have to do some further error checking inside of the callback to make sure that your `$(xml).find()` is returning what you expect it to.